# " Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' " javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this error showing on my console although everything is working fine, I have divs of books name, and beside them a button "delete.
at the bottom I have a form with the button "add", I am trying to add and delete books according to event "click" and it works fine, but I'm wondering what this error means? "script.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
at HTMLDivElement. (script.js:9)"

[image: here is my code]

Comment: Please include all relevant information/code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try switching around the `.removeChild()` function like below:

```
booklist.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.className == 'rem') {
    var bookdiv=e.target.parentElement;
    bookdiv.removeChild(booklist);
  }
}
```

Another approach is to delete the `bookdiv`.

```
booklist.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.className == 'rem') {
    var bookdiv=e.target.parentElement;
    bookdiv.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you :))) , I tried the remove() method it works without showing the error, but do you know what is the difference?

Comment: `bookdiv.removeChild(booklist)` removes the booklist element, which is found inside the `bookdiv` element. All it does is look inside the `bookdiv` element. `bookdiv.remove()`, on the other hand, removes the whole `bookdiv` element and its child elements completely.